# Rollover popup based on mouse click location

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, positioning

I need a rollover popup based on mouse click location (I cannot exactly use a CSS absolute positionined div inside a relative one for this, since that kind of crops my popup...reason being I have overflow:hidden for layout purpose)

So I cannot use this;

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <ul class="popup"><li> item 1</li><li> item 2</li></ul>
    <img src="someImg.gif" width="100" height="100"/>
</div>

.wrapper {
    position: relative;
}

.popup {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 105px;
    left: 10px;
}

.wrapper:hover .popup {
    display: block;
}
```

[image]

So can I get something based on mouse cursor location and it should be completely fluid (no fixed "px" value  and should adjust as the browser is resized)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well u are on the right way to prevent the cropping of pop up give the class css z-index of a 1000+ value n d class wrapper a z-index of less or -1 value